# Make images on last row the same size as others in flexbox gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox, image-gallery

I'm attempting to build a very simple CSS flex image gallery that shrinks the width of the images depending on the size of the container:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="small-thumb-dpi.jpg" />
        <div>this is the item description</div>
    </div>

    ...(more items here)

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

The problem I have is maybe because I'm using "flex: 1 1 auto;" for the gallery items, like so:

```
.grid-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 236px;
    margin: .35vw;        
}
```

The code above creates the flex grid I'm looking for except the images on the last row expand to fill the available space, like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: lightgray;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin: .45vw;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
    <div classs=item-description>This is the item description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/okcancel/pen/wWWYWp)

Basically, I  need the images on the last row to be the same size as the others while the flex property of the images is maintained. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the width of the .grid-item and add margin if you want gutters.

```
.grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a little ninja donkey.

- On each donkey, set the `flex-basis` from `auto` to a tolerable percentage, I chose `25%`.

  ```
  flex:1 1 25%
  ```
- Next add an extra donkey and assign `visibility: hidden` on the ninja donkey.

  ```
  .grid-item:last-of-type {
     visibility: hidden;
  }
  ```

Btw, I changed the divs for each donkey into `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` respectively.

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/QEEJOw?editors=1100)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .grid-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .grid-item {
      background-color: lightgray;
      flex: 1 1 25%;
      width: 300px;
      margin: .45vw;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .grid-item:last-of-type {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .grid-item img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    figcaption {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZsY7k0WAAA_sk5.jpg" />
      <figcaption>This is the item description</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That almost fixed it; if I add or remove items, then the last one that is not hidden expands again. And If I set the value of the **flex-basis** property to a length like 25%, the items won't "float" if the container grows or shrinks.